# jest Mocking a jQuery function from a promise

Tags: javascript, jquery, jestjs

I have a function that calls a jQuery function.
the jQuery function called `dataFunc` and should return an object.

I want to test the promise, not the `dataFunc` function.
For that, I want to mock the response that `dataFunc` should return

I want this row `const { data } = await service.auth( buttonData );` `data` to return
 `{ access_level: 0 }`;

How can I do that?

This is my code:

This function with the promise I want to test:

```js
auth(buttonData){
  const myPromise = new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
    const success = (e, data) => {
      resolve({data, error: null});
    };

    const error = () => {
      resolve({data: null, error: 'Error'});
    };

    jQuery(buttonData).dataFunc({
      success,
      error,
    });
  });
  return myPromise;
}
```

This is what I have done in jest so far:

```js
describe('service.test.js', () => {
  beforeEach(() => {
    global.jQuery = () => {
      return {
        dataFunc: jest.fn(() => ({access_level: 0})),
      };
    };
  });

  afterEach(() => {
    jest.clearAllMocks();
  });

  test('should do something', async () => {
    // Arrange
    const service = new Service();
    const approveButton = document.createElement('button');

    // Act
    const {data} = await service.auth(buttonData);
    console.log(data);
  });
});
```

Comment: What is `dataFunc` a custom plugin?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To fulfill `auth` function you need either reject or resolve the value.

However, when you mock jQuery method `dataFunc` to return an explicit value, you override the default behavior and it never calls resolve or reject. Therefore your promise will hang.

You don't necessarily need to mock but provide the original functionality `dataFunc` carries or provide one that is necessary for the current test.

To fix your example you can pass the argument and call it.

```js
global.jQuery = () => {
  return {
    dataFunc: ({success, error}) => {
      success(jest.fn(), {access_level: 0})
    },
  };
};
```

Comment: How can I imitate a rejected promise? 
e.g, I want to test the result of a failed promise.
in my `auth`function the error is also a resolved request.

Comment: If I do this:  
`global.jQuery = () => {
   return {
    elementorConnect: ( { success, error } ) => {
     // success( jest.fn(), null );
     error( jest.fn(), 'Unable to connect' );
    },
   };
  };`
I receive the error inside the success.
How can simulate the error inside the `error` const in `auth` func

Comment: Correct, you just need to call `error` instead of `success` but you have a mistake in your `auth` example. You `resolve` inside error fn which should be `reject`

Comment: I pass the error in the resolve in order to avoid catch.

Comment: can you please take a look at this question?
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/73647781/jest-mocking-a-jquery-function-data-in-order-it-receives-desired-params