# Jest Mocking a jQuery function data in order it receives desired params

Tags: javascript, jquery, jestjs

in Continue to an earlier question
[jest Mocking a jQuery function from a promise](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/73637975/jest-mocking-a-jquery-function-from-a-promise)

I want to know If I can test the properties that are added to `dataFunc` function.

this is what I want to test:

1. buttonData - check that it is actually a button and not some other element.
2. url - this param can be a function like this: `(url) => url.replace('##a##', 'sometext')`
3. dimensions - this is an object that looks like this: `{ width: 100, height: 200 }`

**I am not looking for someone to solve this for me, just to point me in the right direction.**

this is the func:

```
auth( buttonData, url, dimensions ){
  return new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
    const success = (e, data) => {
      resolve({data, error: null});
    };

    const error = () => {
      resolve({data: null, error: 'Error'});
    };

    jQuery(buttonData).dataFunc({
      success,
      error,
      url,
      dimensions 
    });
  });
}
```

I know I can do it using `toHaveBeenCalledWith` but I do not understand how to mock the params I mentioned earlier in the jquery func.

This is what I have done so far...
I know it is wrong...

```
        test( 'check that service receives the desired variables', async () => {
            const approveButton = document.createElement( 'button' );
  
  // I am pretty sure that this is not correct as this mocks the returning data from dataFunc       
    global.jQuery = () => {
                return {
                    dataFunc: ( { url, dimenssions } ) => {
                        url( jest.fn(), ( url ) => url.replace('##a##', 'sometext') );
                        dimenssions( jest.fn(), { width: 100, height: 200 } );
                    },
                };
            };
        
            const service = await service.auth( approveButton, url, dimenssions );
        
            expect( service ).toHaveBeenCalledWith( approveButton, url, dimenssions );
        } );
```

Comment: At least, you may use jest.mock, instead of changing the global jQuery object directly.

Answer (score 0):

```js
const mockDataFunc = jest.fn()

global.jQuery = (buttonData) => {
    return {
        dataFunc: (params) => mockDataFunc(buttonData, params),
    };
};

expect(mockDataFunc).toBeCalledWith(
    expect.any(Object),
    expect.objectContaining({
        url: expect.stringContaining("something"),
        dimenssions: expect.objectContaining({ width: 100, height: 200 })
    })
)
```